# Escape and download URL using Ruby

Tags: ruby, uri, rest-client

I'm trying to download the HTML content from a URL without success.

Here is the URL:

```
http://example.com/some_string[value]
```

When use RestClient I get this error:

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?)
```

I got some help from the Ruby on Rails IRC. The Idea is to escape the end of the URL.

```
$ "http://example.com/" + CGI::escape("some_string[value]")
=> "http://example.com/some_string%5Bvalue%5D"
```

The generated URL does not work, I'm getting a 404.
It works in the browsers though.

Anyone knows how to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [URI RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt):

> Other characters are excluded because gateways and other transport
>     agents are known to sometimes modify such characters, or they are
>     used as delimiters.
>
> unwise      = "{" | "}" | "|" | "\" | "^" | "[" | "]" | "`"
>
> Data corresponding to excluded characters must be escaped in order to
>     be properly represented within a URI.

Trusting a browser's response or ability to handle a link is risky. They do everything they can to return a page, instead of enforcing the standards, so they are not authoritative sources whether a page or URL is correctly defined.

RestClient's response is probably based on URI's, which returned the same error when I tested parsing the URL using URI.

I haven't ever seen a URL using unencoded "[" and "]" characters.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfect. I used this to escape the URL. `url.gsub(/\{|\}|\||\\|\^|\[|\]|\`|\s+/) { |m| CGI::escape(m) }` I escaped every character in the regexp, just in case :)